# How do I test a list in a JUnit test?

Tags: java, eclipse, list, testing, junit

I have created a Survey.java class and a SurveyTest.java JUnit test. But I am not sure how to test the list in the Survey class. How can I test them in the JUnit test?

Survey.java

```
package com.jhaksurvey.model;

import java.util.List;

public class Survey {

private long id;
private String title;
private boolean active = true;
private List<Question> questions;

public Survey() {

}

public Survey(long id, String title) {
this.id=id;
this.title=title;   
}

public long getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public boolean isActive() {
return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
this.active = active;
}

public List<Question> getQuestions() {
return questions;
}

public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
this.questions = questions;
}

}
```

SurveyTest.java

```
package com.survey.model.test;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import com.survey.model.Survey;


public class SurveyTest extends TestCase {

private Survey survey;

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();  
    survey = new Survey();
}

public void testSurvey() {
    survey.toString();
}

public void testSurveyLongString() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testGetId() {
    long expected = (long) Math.random();
    survey.setId(expected);
    long actual = survey.getId();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

public void testGetTitle() {
    String expected = "surveytitle";
    survey.setTitle(expected);
    String actual = survey.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);  
}

public void testIsActive() {
    Boolean expected = true;
    survey.setActive(expected);
    Boolean actual = survey.isActive();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

public void testGetQuestions() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

}
```

Comment: You're basically testing if setters and getters are working - in your case, these are so simple that there is no added value in this. You're testing the basics of Java and JVM (variable assignment / read) which is a bloat.  
If you add some relevant business logic to your class, than it's appropriate to test it. Testing setters and getters is good only for artificially increasing code coverage indicator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no real logic in that class, so you don't need to test this class. You should only be testing classes that contain logic of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Survey.java is a model/data structure to hood values. Ideally you should be testing the class which is using Survey class. For ex. CreateSurvey may be the class which is creating a survey, so you can unit test the create method to make sure it is appropriately setting the values for the survey object.

Answer (score 0):

you can test whether the list is null or not